# Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ random variables. Show that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ random variables and
>   \begin{align}U &= X + Y + Z\\ V &= X -Z\\ T &= 2X -Y + Z\end{align}
>   are independent. Verify that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

I know that if $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independent random variables and $g_{1},g_{2}$ are real functions, then if we define $Y_{1}:=g_{1}(X_{1})$ and $Y_{2}:=g_{2}(X_{2})$, then $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are independent. Is this sufficient to show that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent?

Any help will be appreciated. Regards

Comment: Mutually independent or pairwise independent?

Comment: I think two by two, independent

Comment: This seems as wrong as can be (note for example that $5X=U+2V+T$, $5Y=3U+V-2T$ and $5Z=U-3V+T$ hence there is no reason that the covariances of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, when they exist, should be zero).